# How can I efficiently compare my data with a remote database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I need to update my contacts database in SQL Server with changes made in a remote database (also SQL Server, on a different server on the same local network). I can't make any changes to the remote database, which is a commercial product. I'm connected to the remote database using a linked server. Both tables contain around 200K rows.

My logic at this point is very simple: [simplified pseudo-SQL follows]

```
/* Get IDs of new contacts into local temp table */

Select remote.ID into #NewContactIDs
From Remote.Contacts remote
Left Join Local.Contacts local on remote.ID=local.ID
Where local.ID is null

/* Get IDs of changed contacts */

Select remote.ID into #ChangedContactIDs
From Remote.Contacts remote
Join Local.Contacts local on remote.ID=local.ID
Where local.ModifyDate < remote.ModifyDate

/* Pull down all new or changed contacts */

Select ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, ...
Into #NewOrChangedContacts
From Remote.Contacts remote
Where remote.ID in (
        Select ID from #NewContactIDs 
        union 
        Select ID from #ChangedContactIDs
    )
```

Of course, doing those joins and comparisons over the wire is killing me. I'm sure there's a better way - advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider maintaining a lastCompareTimestamp (the last time you did the compare) in your local system.  Grab all the remote records with ModifyDates > lastCmpareTimestamp and throw them in a local temp table.  Work with them locally from there.

Comment: Not a bad idea - out of curiosity, where would you store lastCompareTimestamp?

Comment: Probably in a new table in the local database.  Possibly overkill, but it gives you an always accessible and easily updated location.

Answer (score 0):

The last compare date is a great idea

One other method I have had great success with is SSIS (though it has a learning curve, and might be overkill unless you do this type of thing a lot):

Make a package

Set a data source for each of the two tables. If you expect a lot of change pull the whole tables, if you expect only incremental changes then filter by mod date. Make sure the results are ordered

Funnel both sets into a Full Outer Join

Split the results of the join into three buckets: unchanged, changed, new

Discard the unchanged records, send the new records to an insert destination, and send the changed records to either a staging table for a SQL-based update, or - for few rows - an OLEDB command with a parameterized update statement.

OR, if on SQL Server 2008, use Merge